# Spring-Cloud-Config not getting properties

Tags: spring, runtime-error, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I cannot Create properties as I get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configClient': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'user.role' in value "${user.role}"

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration

I am using

```
@Value("${user.role}")
```

and

```
@Value("${user.role:}")
```

does not fetch any information.

Comment: That's not enough information to help identify any problems.

Comment: Hard to say without more information, if you are using a yaml file vs a properties file.  That might be causing it.

Comment: @code you are right, that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue that you when I tried the tutorial. It seems the client can't achieve the server to resolve the property 'user.role', in my case, the error was the wrong property:

```
spring.application.name: config-client
```

You can check the configurations of the server, If you can access your github repo with configs. With server running, like this:

```
curl http://root:s3cr3t@localhost:9090/config-client/development/master                                                                                                                                                                         [13:26:43]
{"name":"config-client","profiles":["development"],"label":"master","version":"80d048de5faa3314429a1fce1645917786da28d6","state":null,"propertySources":[{"name":"https://gitlab.com/marcosnasp/spring-config-baeldung-tutorial.git/config-client-development.properties","source":{"user.role":"Developer"}}]}%
```

I used the the yml config for both, and a different port for the server 9090, the client port by default, since I have not configured in application.properties is the 8080, client and server, at looks like:

the client config:

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-client
  profiles:
    active: development
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:9090
      username: root
      password: s3cr3t
      fail-fast: true
```

the server config:

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: delivery-config-server
  encrypt:
    key-store:
      location: classpath:/config-server.jks
      password: my-s70r3-s3cr3t
    alias: config-server-key
    secret: my-k34-s3cr3t
```

application.yml:

```
server:
    port: 9090

spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://gitlab.com/marcosnasp/spring-config-baeldung-tutorial.git
          timeout: 10
          clone-on-start: true
  security:
    user:
      name: root
      password: s3cr3t
```

Comment: For more information, please see this repo: [link] (https://github.com/marcosnasp/spring-config-baeldung-tutorial)